# Cannot install newly published Packagist package with composer

Tags: php, installation, composer-php, version, packagist

I just published my first package on Packagist: https://packagist.org/packages/felixfbecker/advanced-json-rpc.

I tagged the first commit with version `v1.0.0`, which Packagist detects correctly.
When trying to install the package with composer

```
composer require felixfbecker/advanced-json-rpc
```

I get

```
[UnexpectedValueException]
Invalid version string ""
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, badge is fine now, but still can't install :/

Answer (score 0):

Try add some  minimum-stability into the composer.json file

```
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
```

Or

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable" : true
```

and then update the packag in https://packagist.org

https://igor.io/2013/02/07/composer-stability-flags.html

Comment: Do you mean in the composer.json of the library or the composer.json of the project? Also
> Remember though: Most likely the reason why you need those stability flags is because the maintainers of your dependencies did not tag stable releases. You should go and annoy them right now so they add branch-aliases and tag releases. And as soon as they do, you can nuke those stability flags and be happy again.

How can I tag a stable release?

Answer (score 0):

After all, it was not a problem with the *published* package, but with the project's composer.json.